# Working with large csv files

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I'm trying to find out some of the best ways to work with large data files.  I have a scenario where I will have several CSV files, of which I would like the ability to query data.  One of the csv files I will read line by line but I need to be able to query a second CSV file based on a key from the line I'm currently reading.  I don't want to (at least I don't think) load the entire CSV into a memory object as they can be millions of lines and will eat tons of RAM.  I've considered writing them to some sort of database file on the fly but that just doesn't seem efficient as your essentially duplicating the data.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Open the ones that need to be read line by line in 25% chunks on different threads

Comment: May be you can consider a background service that runs to move your CSV file to database. Then you can make SQL queries easily

Comment: the requirement is not clear, maybe you just need one single line of the 1st CSV to do the query, if that is the case, `StreamReader.ReadLine()` is sufficient. if you do need all the keys from 1 million lines to do the query, then, you don't have a better choice.

Comment: What makes you think that copying the data into a database is inefficient? A database is more than a storage mechanism. It also has indices...It is a common optimization, copying data into a form that is easily read...heck we even do it in real life with books and the internet...

Comment: Unless the CSV file that you are doing random queries on is _really_ large then just having it in storage is what I'd recommend. The KISS principle. As an alternative, how about read it and note the keys and the offset into the file, so then you can read the individual lines when needed.

Comment: Why write another csv parser? There can be tricky bits in them. Use something off the shelf like Linq to CSV, unless you are in complete control of what is in the csv files, and can safely ignore many of the potential issues.

Comment: I sounds like you want random access, but row length is variable in a csv file, so I don't see how that's achievable. Either bring it all in memory, or write it to a db or some file format where you can fetch rows directly. I'd try memory first.

Answer (score -1):

You can try OleDb, load data in data table using data adapter, and perform query on it. This [link](http://rudesyle.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/using-linq-to-query-a-csv-file/) has explained

```
String conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\;
    Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited""";

OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM C:\Temp\teams.csv", cn);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

cn.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Answer does not take into account the OP's concerns on RAM usage.

Comment: @Suresh loading it in to memory isn't really an option at this point.  These files could have 1-2 million rows with 30 columns.  It appears that throwing them in to a database on the fly is my best bet.

Comment: I understand, and yes in that case above solution will not work.